# C# Ending Regex statement

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
Regex.Match(contents, @"Security=(?<Security>\D+)").Groups["Security"].Value;
```

this makes the following:

> Security=SSPI;Database=Datab_ob

How do I make the Regex cut off at ; so i would only get Security=SSPI

Comment: If you put four spaces before each line of code it gets formatted as code. This means the HTML sanitizer won't eat tag-like stuff, like the <Security> group name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Match(contents, "Security=(?<Security>[^;]+)").Groups["Security"].Value
```

Comment: +1; Anytime you have a text delimiter that's defined by some external constraint (like the use of ';' in the connection string parsing logic in .NET) using that as a negative character class makes for a simple and reliable regex.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 "Security=(?<Security>\D+?);"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could to use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look for the ; after your string, but not to match it.  Using this:

```
Security=(?<Security>\w+(?=;))
```

as the regex pattern will get any words after the '=' and before the ';' into the Security named group

Comment: That's if you want there to be a ; after the Security line. It could also be at the end of the connection string.